# How can I use my existing Time Machine drive on the network?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I have an external HD that I've been using as a time machine for my MBP.  Here's what I want to do:

- attach the drive to my desktop machine
- configure time machine on my MBP to use the drive as a time machine through the network
- **retain my existing backups...**

So I want time machine to continue using the same backups it always did when the drive was connected locally.  **I do not want to start from scratch.**

I know how to set time machine to use a network drive rather than a locally attached drive, but it doesn't recognize the existing backups (it wants to start over).  I'm not afraid of the terminal... how can I get this working?

#### on edit:

I got a large drive to use during the conversion, but the link below didn't help because there was no hex id to be found on my machine in the second step  :/

Comment: Have a look @ this question : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/is-it-possible-to-use-time-machine-on-a-shared-usb-hardrive

Comment: @Pierre: I found a site that describes the process, but I need about 640GB free space somewhere to do the conversion and I don't have that right now :/  http://rolf.haynberg.de/?p=83

Comment: You can delete your previous backups (that will be useless) before doing your fist backup over wifi...

Comment: Ya but I don't have another disk that has enough space to copy over the old backups first so I can copy them back after I've followed the instructions on that page I linked.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to convert your current local-style Time Machine into a sparsebundle before it will be usable in TM over the network. You'll need some temporary storage somewhere to create your converted backup into during this conversion.

I don't know the exact conversion procedure but here are some Google'd links:
http://www.tidbits.com/Talk/1960
http://jason-townsend.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-transfer-local-time-machine.html

Something along the lines of `hdiutil convert -format UDSB`

Comment: +1... sorry I haven't had a chance to mess with this yet but when I do I'll put some feedback on here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mountain Lion, you can create a sparse bundle disk image, enable owners on that image, and copy over the "Backups.backupdb" folder from your Time Machine drive into the sparsebundle image using Finder